# Javascript: how to assign setter to object via `=` sign?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, getter-setter

Is there way to assign setter/getter to existing object via `=` sign?

```
window.somesetter = set(v) {};
window.somesetter = function set(v) {};
window.somesetter = set settername(v) {};
```

Comment: Do you want to have multiple different setter functions with the same name/under the same property?

Comment: I want to have one setter for one property, with the same name if it's possible and without `Object.define()`.

Comment: What is the problemt with `Object.defineProperty`? The question sounds like [The XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say no. But the answer is "kinda yes" if you use a proxy instead of the object itself.

But this is black magic and by all means is *NOT recommended* for production :)

```js
const winProxy = new Proxy(window, {
  set(target, name, value) {
    if (typeof value === 'function' && {set: 1, get: 1}[value.name]) {
      const descriptor = Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, name) || {
        enumerable: false, 
        configurable: true,
      }
      
      descriptor[value.name] = value
      
      Reflect.defineProperty(target, name, descriptor)
      
    } else {
      Reflect.set(target, name, value)
    }
  }
})

winProxy.someProp = function set(v) {
  console.log('setter', v);
}

winProxy.someProp = function get() {
  console.log('getter')
}

window.someProp = 1;
window.someProp
```

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't.

If you want to assign a setter or getter to an existing object, use `defineProperty`.

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'setter', {
  set: function(value) { window.test = value }
});

window.setter = "Hello";
console.log(window.test);
```

Comment: This will make a property with `configurable` and `enumerable` false, which isn't the same.

Answer (score -5):

Try this form:

```
window.somesetter = function (v) {};
```

Comment: This is neither a [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) / [`setter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) nor different from the second example in OP's question.